# Операторы Lua в C# операторы (необычное сравнение)

Tags: c#, массивы, lua, сравнение, операторы

Никак не могу понять как перевести этот оператор из Lua в C# оператор?

```
--Это некая карта из массива байт
--0x0 используется как ничего, а 0x1 как стена
local map = {
{ 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1 },
{ 0x1, nil, nil, 0x1 },
{ 0x1, nil, 0x1, 0x1 },
{ 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1 },
}

local yMap, xMap = math.floor(player.y / 32), math.floor(player.x / 32)

if map[yMap] and map[yMap][xMap] then
    return map[yMap][xMap]
end
```

Ну к сути - Я никак не понимаю как это вообще работает в Lua?

Я про строчку с сравнением: `if map[yMap] and map[yMap][xMap] then`

Я пытался понять и написать это на C#

```
if ((map[yMap] != 0x0) & (map[yMap][xMap] != 0x0))
```

Но все тщетно, компилятор конечно же ругается что я сравниваю byte[] и byte.
Никак не пойму почему на Lua это работает?! Может он берет байт от начала массива?

И да, как я правильно понял:

`if map[0] then` и `if map[0] not nil then` это одно и тоже?

То есть Если НЕ nil вернет true?

-

В Lua почти ничего не знаю, просто нужно Lua скрипт в C# перенести, пожалуйста, объясните глупцу, как это работает?

Comment: А чего так в лоб то? То что нормально для скриптового языка - не годится для строго типизированного. Так чтоб это все перевести нужен контекст - что именно делает этот код в контексте остального. И переделать придется многое прям от самого основания.

Comment: Ложью является только `false` и `nil`. "if map[yMap] and map[yMap][xMap] then" - сначала проверяется существование `map[yMap]` (нолики и пустые строки тоже подходят), затем существование `map[yMap][xMap]`

Comment: А `if map[0] not nil then` вызывает ошибку. Ключом таблицы может быть и false (а вообще, все кроме nil): `if map[0]~=nil then`. И в луашных массивах индексы с 1 - в map всегда не сработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if map[yMap] - да это тоже самое что спросить map[yMap]  существует?
В строго типизированных языках двумерный массив определен заранее, как у вас. И эту проверку можно опустить.

```
      public struct Coord    { public int x, y;  }      

           Coord player;        
        player.y = 3992;
        player.x = 62;

        int[,] map = {
            { 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1 },
            { 0x1, 0x0 , 0x0, 0x1 },
            { 0x1, 0x0 , 0x1, 0x1 },
            { 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1 },
            { 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1 }, 
        } ;

        int xMap = (int)Math.Floor( (double) player.x / 32);
        int yMap = (int)Math.Floor( (double) player.y / 32);

        Console.WriteLine(  );

        if (xMap<=map.GetLength(1) & yMap<=map.GetLength(0))  
            if  (map[yMap,xMap] == 0x0) 
              { Console.WriteLine("Ok"); }
            else  Console.WriteLine("None");
        else  Console.WriteLine("Bad index"); 
    }
```

Но если есть необходимость делать проверку, то как-то так:

```
(map.GetType().IsArray) && (map.Rank==2)
```

Comment: `if (map[yMap][xMap] == 0x0)` работает, спасибо! Как я сразу не догадался? Наверное до утра не надо сидеть..

Comment: А если yMap или xMap станет отрицательным или станет больше длины массива (выйдет за индексы границ) в Lua это выход за границы   массива, все там будет считатся как nil?

Comment: если принять что x - это размерность по горизонтали а y по вертикали , то так работает: xMap<=map.GetLength(1) & yMap<=map.GetLength(0)

Comment: Да, я сделал чуть по другому: `if ((yMap < 0 | xMap < 0) | ((map.Length <= yMap) | (map[0].Length <= xMap)))`  Если выйдет за границы - возвратит 0x0, и все работает :)  (У меня GetLenght выдавал ошибку)